# MIPS Assembly - Open File failing

Tags: assembly, io, mips, mars-simulator

I can't seem to open a file with the following MIPS code.

Here I prompt a user for a string filepath, and read the input.

```
.text
.globl main

main:
    li $v0, 0
reprompt_case_return:

    bltz $v0, reprompt_case_print
    # Print prompt.
    la $a0, prompt
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    # Read input string.
    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, buffer
    li $a1, 1024
    syscall
```

Here I load sys code 13 for opening a file, and I make the assumption that $a0 register contains the string filepath address.

```
    # Open file.
    li $v0, 13
    # Note: filename string is already in $a0.
    li $a1, 0  # Flag for reading.
    li $a2, 0  # Mode is ignored.
    syscall

    j return_here
```

My issue is that `$v0` , the file descriptor, contains a neg number.

The below code is the rest of the program logic but I think likely unrelated to the problem.

```
reprompt_case_print:
    # Print prompt.
    la $a0, reprompt
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

return_here:
    # Check if $v0 is less than zero.
    bltz $v0, reprompt_case_return

.data

prompt: .asciiz "Enter the file path to a UTF-8 encoded file: \n"
reprompt: .asciiz "The path was invalid, try re-entering the file-path: \n"
buffer: .space 1024
```

I have tried moving the .jar file where I run the simulator to a folder containing a file, but I'm not able to read it. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Look up that negative number. It's an error code. Also verify that your input string function provides file name suitable for `open`. E.g. it might not be zero terminated or it might include a newline. Use your simulator to check it.

Comment: That I know :), It means the file path wasn't correct. An example of the input string would be "ascii.txt" (quotes removed). What does zero terminated mean? Does it matter that my buffer allocated space is larger than the input filepath string?

Comment: And thank you x100. Edit: Turns out it was that the buffer space allocated was larger than the filepath, and the syscall code 13 method doesn't account for such a thing.

Comment: Removing the null pointer at the end of the file buffer path allowed me to allocate buffer space when it's larger than the filepath

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem as well, and solved it by putting my Mars.jar, .asm file, and the file to read into the same directory.